# Angular Lazy Loading: Lighthouse reports "Remove unused JavaScript" on scripts that should be not loaded yet

Tags: javascript, angular, lazy-loading, lighthouse

I have a problem regarding lighthouse issue on my angular app with lazy loading. Basically my app contains 3 big chunks of feature that should be lazy loaded. So when you open the feature A, I expect the app not to load the scripts for feature B and C at all, and vice versa.

But somehow, when I check with lighthouse, it reports back that I can "remove unused JavaScript" on the other JS files that contains the whole functionality of the other features. Even worse, one of the feature depends on ngx-quill for rich-text editor, and this also got loaded although I open a feature that does not need it.

Am I missing something here?

EDIT:

I have these following *-routing.modules.ts:

- app-routing

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', loadChildren: () => import('./feature-a/feature-a.module').then(m => m.FeatureAModule) },
  { path: 'feature-b', loadChildren: () => import('./feature-b/feature-b.module').then(m => m.FeatureBModule) },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '', pathMatch: 'full' }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { relativeLinkResolution: 'legacy' })
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

- feature-a: nothing of interest, no lazy loading here.
- feature-b:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { LandingPageComponent } from './pages/landing-page/landing-page';
import { FeatureBPage } from './feature-b.page';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: FeatureBPage,
    children: [
      { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
      { path: 'home', component: LandingPageComponent },
      {
        path: 'feature-c',
        loadChildren: () =>
          import('./feature-c/feature-c.module').then(
            (m) => m.FeatureCModule
          ),
      },
      { path: '**', redirectTo: '', pathMatch: 'full' }
    ],
  },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class FeatureBRoutingModule {}
```

- feature-c: contains multiple other lazy loaded features (feature-c1, -c2, -c3, etc), but none of those are being referenced by Feature A and/or Feature B.

Comment: are you sure you defined these modules as lazy? could you provide your app-routing.module.ts file?

Comment: @vitaliykotov I updated my question with the routing-modules files. Thanks!

Comment: I think your LandingPageComponent should also be in a seperate module, just like your `FeatureCModule`. And yes this module contains only 1 page, but the dependencies for this page will not automatically be imported in sibling pages. I guess this is what Lighthouse is complaining about...

Comment: @Pieterjan I thought the basic principle of Lazy Loading is that unused JS will not even be downloaded, hence optimizing initial loading time?

Comment: True. So in your case, when you visit `/feature-b/feature-c`, the dependencies imported in the FeatureBModule will also be loaded while actually you only need these dependencies in your `LandingPageComponent`

Comment: @Pieterjan yes exactly, that I understand. What I do not understand is, when I visit /feature-b, the JS for feature-a and feature-c also get downloaded :/

Comment: You're right. Did you perhaps use `PreloadAllModules` in your `RouterModule.ForRoot` call? However AFAIK Lighthouse should not complain if that's the case...

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the issue is not so much with the unused JavaScript from bundles (scripts) that should not be loaded, but the fact that those bundles are being loaded in the first place.

It's hard to say without further details, but it could be for any of the following reasons:

1. `PreloadAllModules` strategy loads all lazy-loaded modules regardless of their lazy-loading status.
2. "Accidentally" importing something from one lazy-loaded feature module into another module loads that entier lazy-loaded module at run-time.
3. Verify through the `Network` tab that the unrelated lazy-loaded features are indeed being loaded (and you are not confusing other files for them).
4. In case the unused JavaScript is in the bundles that should, in fact, be loaded, Lighthouse reports any piece of code that wasn't executed (e.g. `if` conditions that didn't run, `*ngIf` directives that didn't execute) as unused. There isn't much one can do about that.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I updated my question with the content of the relevant routing modules. I don't see `PreloadAllModules` being set anywhere in my code, so I assume that should not be the problem..